# Image upload in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new in Iphone development. I want to upload image from Iphone library to a server.
I want to take a button on screen, by clecking button user can see the image files and select one file which user want. After selecting file I want to show the image in image view. 

How to do it. How to use ImageViewController?

Thanks,
Avinash Patil.

Comment: SO is not a `gimme teh codez` site. You should try to ask questions that are answerable without having to provide an end-to-end solution. You actually are here to learn and not for someone else to do your work, aren't you?

Comment: I know Till is right but he is telling that he is new..Plz don't underestimate others.. Just help him,how to solve problems

Comment: @Marvin He might be new, but that doesn't prevent him from using Google or the Apple developer site. There's lots of examples on there and he even mentioned ImageViewController in his question. So why not start with trying something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first u have to get image form photo library for that use below code.

```
                   - (IBAction)BrowseImage:(id)sender {

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = 
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                              nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    //newMedia = NO;

  }

  }
         -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
         {
       [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

         }
```

after selecting image u have send that image to server using http post method

here is code

```
                  NSString *urlString = @"your Url";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// file
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self scaleAndRotateImage:Mainimage.image],90);


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"user_photo\"; filename=\"photoes.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",@"ImageNmae"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




// Text parameter1
// NSString *param1 = @"parameter text";
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:ImageTitel.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// set request body
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIImagePickerController and its delegate method, and Implement UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in your controller's .h file

Just write this code for your button click

```
-(IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender
{
        UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgPicker.delegate = self;
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
}
```

When you click on this button UIImagePickercontroller will load, Select any image you want, This delegate method of UIImagePickerController will called

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
    //This is selected image
    UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    YOURIMAGEVIEW.image = img;
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Now search on `ASIHttpRequest` for how to upload images to webserver... Try some 
Googling..