# How do I get image selected by UIImagePicker in UIWebView on certain file input field in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, ios7

I am displaying html file in **UIWebView** which contains **file input field.** When I click on file input field, it opens default UIImagePicker. So I need image selected by that UIIMagePicker in iOS.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: what do you realy want ,you want to display load image from photolibrary to your Webview

Comment: No, I want to get selected image and upload it to server.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190475/image-upload-in-iphone)

Comment: actually I'm not able to get selected image by user in uiwebview. That is the main question??

Answer (score 1):

try to use this `webview` delegate method.i hope so it will help you.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
  {

       //write your image picker code.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load image from photolibrary to `webview` as shown in below

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info    
   {
  NSURL *urlPath = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
  UIImage *cameraImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cameraImage);
  [self.webview loadData:myData MIMEType:@"image/png" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
  [self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```